# Relation between $\Gamma$-percuspidal parabolic subgroups and split parabolic subgroups of real semisimple Lie groups

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be  a reductive algebraic group defined over $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $\Gamma$ be a lattice in $\mathcal{G}:= G(\mathbb{R})$. I am interested in knowing under what conditions on either of $\mathcal{G}$ or $\Gamma$, the set of $\Gamma$-percuspidal parabolic subgroups is same as the set of split proper parabolic subgroups of $\mathcal{G}$. ( The definition of $\Gamma$-percupidal as in the book by Osborne and Warner- The theory of Eisenstein systems). Any suggestions, comments will be helpful.

Comment: Can you state the definition of $\Gamma$-percuspidal to make your question self-contained?

Comment: @Kimball, Here is the definition. Let $(P, S)$ be a split parabolic subgroup of $\mathcal{G}$, where $P = M \cdot A\cdot N$ be the Langlands decomposition per split component $A$ and $S = M \cdot N$. Then $(P,S)$ is called $\Gamma$-percuspidal if for every dominant successor $(P',S')$  of $(P,S)$ following conditions hold. (1) $ \Gamma \cap P' \subset S'$ (2) $N'/N'\cap \Gamma$ is compact (3)$S'/S'\cap \Gamma$ is of finite volume (4) $S/S \cap \Gamma$ is compact.